# jQuery: select ID in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm editing a dropdown questionnaire logic that only allows input into a neighbouring text field when certain answers are selected.

###JavaScript:

```
var allDropdowns = $('.accordion').find('select');

allDropdowns.each(function(index) {
        $(this).change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == 2 || $(this).val() == 4) {
                allComments.eq(index).removeAttr('disabled');
                allComments.eq(index).removeClass('disabled');
                allComments.eq(index).attr('placeholder', 'Please provide a comment');
            } else {
                allComments.eq(index).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                allComments.eq(index).addClass('disabled');
                allComments.eq(index).removeAttr('placeholder');
            }
        });
    });
```

###HTML:

```
<select id="answer[1]" name="answer[1]">
<option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
<option value="2">Partial</option>
<option value="3">No</option>
<option value="4">N/A</option>
```

So what I'm trying to do is add an additional condition: if the select id = "answer[foo]" && $(this).val() == 1, then enable comment.

Apologies for the pseudo code example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the id by

```
var id = this.id;
```

After that you can compare your id and enable/disable the comments.

So your updated code could look like this:

```
allDropdowns.each(function(index) {
    $(this).change(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            id = this.id;

        if ($this.val() == 2 || $this.val() == 4) {
            allComments.eq(index).removeAttr('disabled');
            allComments.eq(index).removeClass('disabled');
            allComments.eq(index).attr('placeholder', 'Please provide a comment');
        } else {
            allComments.eq(index).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            allComments.eq(index).addClass('disabled');
            allComments.eq(index).removeAttr('placeholder');
        }

        if(id == 'id_you_are_looking_for' && $this.val() == 1){
          // enable comments
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Anton: edited as suggested - retrieving the id directly seems to be the better way :)